# ios app reporting crash when reviewed by apple team

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is being rejected by apple review team saying that it is crashing. I used the same build for testing and found no crash.

I tried with TestFlight on many devices but crash is never reported.

My question is why my app doesn't get crashed when tested on other devices when using the same build while it happened for apple review team?

Could you please someone suggest me on this

They said that it mainly crashed on clicking record button, my app has a feature of recording video
Crash log given by apple is as follows

```
Incident Identifier: 5873811E-C349-48C4-8E98-934D33976DEC
CrashReporter Key:   3dabaa2f4f949ee0995bb9046b28c1a047eb74a8
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             bizzCam [6659]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/901860F0-84B5-484A-B0F7-1D7F4AC45387/bizzCam.app/bizzCam
Identifier:          com.domainname.bizzCamApps
Version:             1.0.20.5 (1.0.20)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-08-31 16:34:34.006 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-08-31 16:32:35.576 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x183da422c 0x1959740e4 0x1825e6834 0x10005f460 0x10006dbdc 0x1889b6ec4 0x188850508 0x188cc1214 0x18881426c 0x188812618 0x18884e680 0x18884dd38 0x188820f74 0x188ac2124 0x18881f488 0x183d5bf8c 0x183d5b230 0x183d592e0 0x183c84f74 0x18d5b76fc 0x188886d94 0x100022d04 0x19601ea08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137270 0x19611c000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d515c 0x1961d0000 + 20828
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001960aea9c 0x19604c000 + 404124
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195141414 0x195140000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195160b88 0x195140000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001959743bc 0x19596c000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019515dbb0 0x195140000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019515d738 0x195140000 + 120632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000195974290 0x19596c000 + 33424
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c85020 0x183c7c000 + 36896
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d5b76f8 0x18d5ac000 + 46840
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188886d90 0x188810000 + 486800
12  bizzCam                         0x0000000100022d00 0x10001c000 + 27904
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019601ea04 0x19601c000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137c78 0x19611c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d5770 0x1961d0000 + 22384
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ffdc98 0x195ff0000 + 56472
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ffd59c 0x195ff0000 + 54684
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196001da0 0x195ff0000 + 73120
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ff3998 0x195ff0000 + 14744

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611ce0c 0x19611c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611cc84 0x19611c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d5b46c 0x183c7c000 + 914540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d593c0 0x183c7c000 + 906176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c84f70 0x183c7c000 + 36720
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183763094 0x1836c4000 + 651412
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184ca5db4 0x184bb0000 + 1007028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137498 0x19611c000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d60e70 0x183c7c000 + 937584
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611ce0c 0x19611c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611cc84 0x19611c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d5b46c 0x183c7c000 + 914540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d593c0 0x183c7c000 + 906176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c84f70 0x183c7c000 + 36720
5   WebCore                         0x00000001927ff288 0x192750000 + 717448
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137078 0x19611c000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d2f18 0x1961d0000 + 12056
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001950f0cac 0x1950e8000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018527d610 0x185264000 + 103952
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185278b8c 0x185264000 + 84876
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137078 0x19611c000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d2f18 0x1961d0000 + 12056
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001950f0cac 0x1950e8000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185526ecc 0x185264000 + 2895564
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185526f70 0x185264000 + 2895728
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185278b8c 0x185264000 + 84876
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137078 0x19611c000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d2f18 0x1961d0000 + 12056
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001950f0cac 0x1950e8000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185526ecc 0x185264000 + 2895564
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185526f70 0x185264000 + 2895728
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185278b8c 0x185264000 + 84876
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 8 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611ce0c 0x19611c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611cc84 0x19611c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d5b46c 0x183c7c000 + 914540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d593c0 0x183c7c000 + 906176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c84f70 0x183c7c000 + 36720
5   WebCore                         0x0000000192833510 0x192750000 + 931088
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000185278b8c 0x185264000 + 84876
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611ce0c 0x19611c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611cc84 0x19611c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d5b46c 0x183c7c000 + 914540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d593c0 0x183c7c000 + 906176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c84f70 0x183c7c000 + 36720
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183cd6ff8 0x183c7c000 + 372728
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000184690230 0x184648000 + 295472
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611ce48 0x19611c000 + 3656
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ffff3c 0x195ff0000 + 65340
2   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001862bd6f8 0x1862b8000 + 22264
3   CoreMedia                       0x00000001845bf8f0 0x184584000 + 243952
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611ce0c 0x19611c000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019611cc84 0x19611c000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d5b46c 0x183c7c000 + 914540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183d593c0 0x183c7c000 + 906176
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183c84f70 0x183c7c000 + 36720
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001826f9020 0x1826e0000 + 102432
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001826eba00 0x1826e0000 + 47616
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3db4 0x1961d0000 + 15796
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d3d10 0x1961d0000 + 15632
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0ee4 0x1961d0000 + 3812

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196137c78 0x19611c000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d12c8 0x1961d0000 + 4808
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0edc 0x1961d0000 + 3804

Thread 13 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.cfprefsd.daemon
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001961362b8 0x19611c000 + 107192
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d70fc 0x1961d0000 + 28924
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ffbc14 0x195ff0000 + 48148
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ff4664 0x195ff0000 + 18020
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195ffe314 0x195ff0000 + 58132
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fffc48 0x195ff0000 + 64584
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d1218 0x1961d0000 + 4632
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001961d0edc 0x1961d0000 + 3804

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702e7237
    x4: 0x0000000195161dfd   x5: 0x000000016fde3410   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019a102310  x21: 0x000000019a0eace8  x22: 0x0000000174151e10  x23: 0x0000000196645fa0
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000174151e00  x26: 0x000000019a0e90a8  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fde3370   lr: 0x00000001961d5160
    sp: 0x000000016fde3350   pc: 0x0000000196137270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: what the crash report apple showed

Comment: It could be some steps which you never perform while testing, or you may left with some edge cases. What is the crash

Comment: You can ask Apple to send you the crash report, this should help you figure out what went wrong. Also your crash reporting tool probably requires your app to be relaunched for the crash report to be sent, and Apple probably didn't restart your app after it crashed.

Comment: Please share the crash report that Apple would have sent you and the circumstances that it crash around that they may have sent you. Other then asking for them there isn't much we can say right now.

Comment: Get crash report from apple, also ask them on which iOS version and on which device they are expriencing crash.

Comment: Please tell your issue in brief with crash log.

Answer (score 0):

They get the same problem, my app was working fine in debug and release.
But my app was crashing on simulator, i think apple test our apps on simulator.
You have some functions who can't be call on simulator and you need use respondsToSelector. (for example function to access camera...)

Comment: Yes my app uses camera, I cant test it on simulator

Comment: You call a function who can't be called on simulator to record a video... You have to check if you can call it with respondsToSelector. If you can't you have to display a message for example "camera not available"...

Answer (score -6):

Either the application memory exceed the mobile memory or use are using resources that does not exist in your app might be misspelled.

Comment: This is more a comment then an answer.